# EditorFor helper: show no negative values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have this value:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0}")]
public int mCardNumber { get; set; }
```

And in a view I'm rendering it like this:

```
Card Number: @Html.EditorFor(_item => _item.mCardNumber, Model.mCardNumber)<br />
```

The reason being is that the value is bound to my model. However, if I cannot insert a negative value, it is still possible to go in the negative. An error message will simply be shown. But I've been asked to **not** allow the editor to go in the negative. Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I did had to scrap the editorFor. After much looking around I ended up adding [this plugin by TexoTela](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/).

So here's how my page is rendered:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item.mCardNumber, new { @class = "positive-integer" })
```

And it works!

Comment: can you share what is in your "positive-integer" class?

Comment: Just have a look at the plugin linked in my answer, still works like a charm up to now

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to leverage some JavaScript. Add this JavaScript `function` to your markup or a shared `.js` file.

```
function disallowNegativeNumber(e) 
{
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode == 45) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and then call that `onkeypress="return disallowNegativeNumber(event)"`. You add that via the `htmlAttributes` parameter on the `TextBoxFor` method types. The ones that are more specific than `EditorFor`. You'd build an object like this:

```
new { onkeypress = "return disallowNegativeNumber(event)" }
```

Comment: Yess :) a new solution involving something I've never done. Oh, I will try this and come back with the results soon :)

Comment: @HerveS, looks like you're right. Don't use `EditorFor`, leverage something like `TextBoxFor` if you want a text box.